# How to click on a element which is opacity:0 in protractor

Tags: javascript, webdriver, protractor

I want to click on element which is opacity as '0' by default. On mouse over opacity will change to '1'.
I want o click on that element through java script.
I don't want to use the mouse over events here.
I want to change the css of the element and click on that one.
Can any one give solution.

Thanks
Omprakash.

Comment: 'I don't want to use the mouse over events here'-so which event u prefer?

Comment: browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.opacity='1'",ClearFilterElement).then(function(){
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()',ClearFilterElement);
});
i want to use like this.

Comment: Now Same code is working.